# List by project_id using queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a a table with following values:

```
id    employee_id    project_id
1     1              1
2     2              1
3     3              1
4     4              1
```

How can i list by project_id? using mysql queries?

```
project_id        employee_id        employee_id        employee_id        employee_id
1                 1                  2                  3                  4
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Comment: Yes i know, but this is for an assignment and i need help with this minor query.

Comment: possible duplicate -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns and see Matt Fenwick Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query-

```
SELECT project_id ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id),',',1) AS employee_id1,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id),',',2),',',-1) AS employee_id2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id),',',3),',',-1) AS employee_id3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id),',',4),',',-1) AS employee_id4 FROM my_table GROUP BY project_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT project_id, GROUP_CONCAT(employee_id) FROM Table GROUP BY project_id;

It's can be consider ..??